# 6/8-pin to SATA Power/4 pin Molex cable non-existent?

Tags: dell

I'm having a hard time to find a cable that would convert 8 pin or 6 pin GPU power connector to multiple SATA power connectors. The ones I've found are working in reverse direction, such as: [http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-SATPCIEX8ADP-6-Inch-Express-Adapter/dp/B007Y8FSMQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007Y8FSMQ)

What I'm looking for is the complete opposite of this. After an hour of Google'ing, I have nothing. Is such cable not possible?

**Real problem:**

Dell R720 has a 8-pin female power connector to install GPU cards. As shown:

[image]

What I'd like to have is a cable or a series of cables to convert this power connector to SATA power cable (to use on a U.2 to PCI-E converter to install a NVMe SSD)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A GPU power connector only delivers 12V, whereas a SATA power connector should provide at least 12V and 5V - and optionally 3.3V. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Power_connectors).
That's why you find cables FROM drive power TO GPU, but not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. I was wondering if it'd be still possible to use the optical drive power slot that's on the motherboard that has red cables (5V?) https://www.itcreations.com/images/products/large/F6HJD.jpg and combine it with this slot to make SATA power cables.

Comment: As that connector is only meant to power optical devices it might not be able to deliver enough power. On the other hand, most drives will only consume little power on their 5V input, if any (if one can believe the specifications, WD Reds don't even use the 5V input at all). You could try, but if it goes wrong you might fry your motherboard...